# Why does User.all.each {|u| puts u.id} print all fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code:

```
User.all.each {|u| puts u.id}
```

Prints out all the fields for all records.

How can I change it to only print the `id` field?

Comment: what user contains? is it `array`? what's the output you got and what you want? tell here

Comment: @Michael Durrant, are you executing that code in the rails console? If so, the console always echos out the .all, .first, etc calls with the attributes of each element it returned. It won't do that in your controllers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was unable to replicate this behavior but if you are looking at this in console you may be mistaking the fact that `#each` returns self (and self, a big array of User objects, is then inspected) for the call to each printing all fields. Can you instead run `User.all.each {|u| puts u.id}; nil` to have the console return `nil` after the each and see if the behavior persists?

Comment: a ha! Implicit `return`s strike again!

Answer (score 0):

If you run `puts u`, does it give a hash or an object? If hash, then use `puts u[:id]` or `puts u['id']` rather than `puts u.id`.

Comment: I tried puts u[:id] and u['id'] and they both return all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this irb or rails console, it should print out just the IDs but then the return from your code is the set of users which the console will then print out. Scroll up and you will see the output you expect followed by the print out of all the user objects with full details.